# Get id of an element with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple div boxes with the class `printPic` which will have their own unique id. On hover in/out, toggle the display of `printPicOverlay` which is a child of `printPic`. The way I have it set up now, `printPicOverlay` for all ids are toggled on hover.

What would be the best way to show/hide `printPicOverlay` on hover for each individual id?

```js
$(".printPic").hover(function () {
$(".printPicOverlay").toggle();
}, function () {
$(".printPicOverlay").toggle();
});
```

```css
.printPic{
  height: 10em;
  width: 10em;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

.printPicOverlay{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "printPic" id = "1">
  <div class = "printPicOverlay"></div>
</div>

<div class = "printPic" id = "2">
  <div class = "printPicOverlay"></div>
</div>

<div class = "printPic" id = "3">
  <div class = "printPicOverlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Something like $("#someID").find(".printPicOverlay");

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to add another alternative – this is really easy in plain CSS, without any Javascript/JQuery:

```css
.printPic {
  height: 10em;
  width: 10em;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

.printPicOverlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.printPic:hover .printPicOverlay {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="printPic" id="1">
  <div class="printPicOverlay"></div>
</div>

<div class="printPic" id="2">
  <div class="printPicOverlay"></div>
</div>

<div class="printPic" id="3">
  <div class="printPicOverlay"></div>
</div>
```

It's also probably a bit more performant – using native browser functionality rather than finding elements via jquery.

[Docs on `:hover` pseudoclass](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)

If you want to animate the overlay appearance, it's possible with a bit of tweaking (`visibility` instead of `display` etc.):

```css
.printPic {
  height: 10em;
  width: 10em;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

.printPicOverlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.8) translate(0, 10%);
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s ease-in, transform 0.3s ease-in;
}

.printPic:hover .printPicOverlay {
  transform: scale(1);
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="printPic" id="1">
  <div class="printPicOverlay"></div>
</div>

<div class="printPic" id="2">
  <div class="printPicOverlay"></div>
</div>

<div class="printPic" id="3">
  <div class="printPicOverlay"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead use [**`$(this)`**](http://html-tuts.com/jquery-this-selector/), with `$(this).find()` like:

```
$(this).find(".printPicOverlay").toggle();
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```js
$(".printPic").hover(function () {
$(this).find(".printPicOverlay").toggle();
}, function () {
$(this).find(".printPicOverlay").toggle();
});
```

```css
.printPic{
  height: 10em;
  width: 10em;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

.printPicOverlay{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "printPic" id = "1">
  <div class = "printPicOverlay"></div>
</div>

<div class = "printPic" id = "2">
  <div class = "printPicOverlay"></div>
</div>

<div class = "printPic" id = "3">
  <div class = "printPicOverlay"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

You could use `$(this).find()` similar to the below.

What jQuery [**find**](https://api.jquery.com/find/) does, is get all descendants by the specified selector `.printPicOverlay` and toggle only those matched elements.

Using `$(this)` will use the context of the currently hovered over element only.

```js
$(".printPic").hover(function () {
  $(this).find(".printPicOverlay").toggle();
}, function () {
  $(this).find(".printPicOverlay").toggle();
});
```

```css
.printPic{
  height: 10em;
  width: 10em;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

.printPicOverlay{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "printPic" id = "1">
  <div class = "printPicOverlay"></div>
</div>

<div class = "printPic" id = "2">
  <div class = "printPicOverlay"></div>
</div>

<div class = "printPic" id = "3">
  <div class = "printPicOverlay"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you need to use the `this` keyword to `find()` the `.printPicOverlay` element *within* the hovered `.printPic`, like this:

```js
$(".printPic").hover(function() {
  $(this).find(".printPicOverlay").toggle();
});
```

```css
.printPic {
  height: 10em;
  width: 10em;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

.printPicOverlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="printPic" id="1">
  <div class="printPicOverlay"></div>
</div>
<div class="printPic" id="2">
  <div class="printPicOverlay"></div>
</div>
<div class="printPic" id="3">
  <div class="printPicOverlay"></div>
</div>
```

***However***, it would be much better, and more simple to achieve this in CSS alone. There's no need for JS at all:

```css
.printPic {
  height: 10em;
  width: 10em;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

.printPicOverlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.printPic:hover .printPicOverlay {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="printPic" id="1">
  <div class="printPicOverlay"></div>
</div>
<div class="printPic" id="2">
  <div class="printPicOverlay"></div>
</div>
<div class="printPic" id="3">
  <div class="printPicOverlay"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '> div').toggle(100);// with little animation
```

Just a different approach; I rather use only CSS by @helb.

While you already over the element ; and with toggling you can achieve your target. with little animation if you wish.

```js
$(function(){
   $(".printPic").hover(function () {
      $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '> div').toggle(100); 
   });
});
```

```css
.printPic{
  height: 10em;
  width: 10em;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

.printPicOverlay{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "printPic" id = "1">
  <div class = "printPicOverlay"></div>
</div>

<div class = "printPic" id = "2">
  <div class = "printPicOverlay"></div>
</div>

<div class = "printPic" id = "3">
  <div class = "printPicOverlay"></div>
</div>
```